# Entities in multiple projects

Tags: java, spring, eclipselink

I have a Spring project which works fine. I have now the requirement to split the project into two pieces - mainly due to use parts of the existing project in another one. While splitting up I'm facing a problem I do not understand and have no real clue what's the source of the issue. E.g.

```
+ -- myTestProject
  | -- PersonEntity
  | -- persistence.xml
  | -- pom.xml
+ -- myBaseProject
  |
  | -- PhoneEntity
  | -- pom.xml
```

When I keep the PhoneEntity in `myTestProject` I can launch Tomcat without problems. When I separate the entities like above I get from `EclipseLink` the  error message:

`The type [class com.smith.PhoneEntity] for the attribute [phoneEntity] on the entity class [class com.smith.Company] is not a valid type for a serialized mapping. The attribute type must implement the Serializable interface.`

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="eclipselink" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">   

        <description>Application managed persistence unit</description>
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/ecoiDS</non-jta-data-source>   
        <class>com.smith.PersonEntity</class>
        <class>com.smith.PhoneEntity</class>
        <class>com.smith.Company</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="WARNING" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="false" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="false" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
            <property name=""/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The `persistence.xml` has included the `PhoneEntity` as well. The whole project compiles well. But somehow I cannot launch the project. Any hints available how to solve the issue?

Comment: you should show the relevant part of `persistence.xml`. The answer is maybe there.

Comment: updated with the `persistence.xml`

Comment: "to split the project into two pieces" what do you mean by pieces? if you mean Modules, then you could create a third Module for the jpa classes, including the Entities and the persistence.xml

Comment: By `modules` you mean Java9-`modules`? Or what do you mean with it? `split up into two pieces` means that I have one existing project which should still run. Than carve out some base into a base project - which could be reused in another project. Which result in the constellation that some entities belong to the base project while others not. But most of all I do not know what `Eclipselink` is complaining about. Since all of the entities are mentioned in the `persistence.xml`

Comment: thanx, please check what I have just written in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to [Create a Multi Module Project](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/);

I would recommend that: you create a third module in which you add all entities as well as the `persistence.xml` file, then you add a dependency of that module in your `Base` and `Test` modules.

You could find a practical example here -> [Spring Boot Multimodule project example](https://github.com/DISID/disid-proofs/tree/master/spring-boot-multimodule).

Comment: So you mean to have one `EntityProject` which consists of all `Entities`, gathered in the `persitence.xml`. So, e.g. `JPARepro<PhoneEntity, Integer>` comes to the `Base` project. And these I could use within the `Test` project - just by adding the dependencies? Did I understand it properly that the main diff in the `pom.xml` is the `<packaging>` attribute?

Comment: Just in the `<dependencies>` like this: `<dependency>
   <groupId>com.project</groupId>
   <artifactId>db_model</artifactId>
  </dependency>`

Comment: I would prefer to follow Spring tutrial which I have mentioned in the answer, it will take ^30 min then you would find out how to manage the project just from maven ;)